# Accessing C macros in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, swift, c-preprocessor

I have a third party C library exporting lots of *preprocessor macros* with arguments.

Problem is when I try to access them in Swift it fails with:

> Unable to resolve the symbol.

What is the way to access such C macros, exported by third party libraries, in Swift?

I do not want to workaround by directly calling functions with name starting with `__` and make my code look ugly nor do want to edit/hack third party library.

Comment: Please read [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C: Preprocessor Directives](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID31)

Comment: This document doesn't answers the question and I am surprised there is no direct way to access macros in C header files?

Comment: In other words, only way is to modify C header files or directly call __ function names! Pretty bad.

Comment: Could you give us some example?

Comment: There are many examples, #define myinit(A,B) __myinit(A,B,sizeof(B)), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy answer. The aforementioned [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID31) states this pretty clearly:

> Complex macros are used in C and Objective-C but have no counterpart in Swift.

But, if you really need to call those (ugly!) C macros, you could define  C99 `inline` functions around them (and call those instead from your Swift code).

For instance, given this C macro:

```
#define SQUARE(n) n * n
```

Define this C function in another header file:

```
inline double square(double n) {
    return SQUARE(n);
}
```

Not the *exact* same thing I'm aware — note that I had to commit to the `double` number type; those crazy text/symbol manipulation won't work either; etc — but might get you halfway there :)

---

**Pure Swift alternative**. Of course, you could also convert *all* those C macros to idiomatic Swift functions by hand, using *protocols*, *generics*, etc to emulate some of the C macros magic.

If I went this route — being the paranoid engineer that I'm! — I would compare the MD5 of the original, converted header against the current file version and fail the Xcode build if both hashes don't match.

This could easily be done by a *pre-action* [build script](https://gist.github.com/acrookston/55d69a16cd5363426dbf7a3d6a9ee6ce) such as:

```
test EXPECTED_HASH != $(md5 HEADER_PATH) && exit 1
```

If this build step fails, then it's time to review your (manually) converted Swift code and update the `EXPECTED_HASH` afterwards :)

Comment: I eventually had to make a new swift file and convert all macros to swift functions. Imagine huge libraries like FFMpeg or OpenCV that would be having so many C macros for functions, how would one translate them!

Comment: @DeepakSharma Looks like a really fun job to me, haha :)