# Swift: can't find function in imported c library

Tags: c, swift

I've been gnawing bones on this for the past day and can't find a solution to it.

I'm creating a swift wrapper for cfitsio which is a fits format for astronomers:

https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/

I've created a basic swift wrapper to access the above as `cFitsIO`, as a module, following the below tutorial:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/87/how-to-wrap-a-c-library-in-swift

When I do swift run on the wrapper's `main.swift` file, I can see that the import is successful, but one of the functions, `fits_open_file` cannot be resolved. The reason why I say the import works is because swift proposes another function which is in the c library as an alternative.

The cfitsio page says to only include `fitsio.h`, so I'm expecting all functions to be called from there.

However upon cloning the GitHub and performing some grep, I can't find any signature for the `fits_open_file` function.

one more thing, when I create the swift wrapper, I use the `pig-config --type system-module` as I can also download cfitsio via brew, which puts it in my system `/usr/local/include` folder.

I read somewhere else about Xcode not properly finding nested headers, in the following link, but fitsio has a lot of header files, some with constants some with macros etc. I would expect a cleaner way of doing this import rather than tediously go through what each header file should have?

https://medium.com/shopify-mobile/wrapping-a-c-library-in-swift-part-1-6dd240070cef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look at the source code provided on the nasa.gov site you referred to, one can see that `fits_open_file` is actually a macro defined in `longnam.h` as a call to `ffopentest`. The `longnam.h` header is included in `fitsio.h`, so the macro would be available if it was used in C/C++ code.

The problem is that Swift automatically imports only simple, constant-like macros, see this Apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_macros_in_swift.

Here is a related SO post: [Accessing C macros in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663917/accessing-c-macros-in-swift)

Comment: Yes, I had found that issue while tracing back all the define statements. I'm able to call on these directly using swift but now it's about getting this to work in a package as a dependency. You got the answer though :)